# Передача значения переменной класса в структуру в этом же классе С++

Tags: c++

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему. Не знаю, как записать и в сети найти не получается.
В main инициализирован объект класса DijkstraAlgorythm, в самом классе есть поле int isOriented, которому присваивается значение:

```
int main() {
DijkstraAlgorythm object;
object.isOriented = 1;
```

В самом классе:

```
class DijkstraAlgorythm {
public:
int isOriented;
struct Graph
{

    vector<vector<int>> matrix;
    Graph(int size)
    {
        matrix.resize(size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            matrix[i].resize(size, infinity);
    }
    void set_edge(int id1, int id2, int cost)
    {
        matrix[id1][id2] = cost;
        if (isOriented == 0)
        matrix[id2][id1] = cost;
    }
};
```

Идея такая: если isOriented = 0, то граф неориентированный и стоимость прохода до вершин устанавливается туда-обратно одинаковая, если ориентированный - только в одну сторону.
Как **в структуру** Graph вытащить значение переменной isOriented?
Заранее большое спасибо.

Comment: Непонятно, зачем тута эти классы... Передавайте как параметр, ну или еще одно поле сделайте.

Comment: У меня не получается передать как параметр:

Ошибка C2327 DijkstraAlgorythm::isOriented: не является именем типа, статическим членом или перечислителем

Comment: В примере ничего такого нету.

Comment: Можно как-то при таких исходных сделать так, чтобы работало?)
Что исправить в самом коде?

Comment: Я же написал - Передавайте как параметр, ну или еще одно поле сделайте.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, как конкретно передать как параметр и что именно. В set_edge сделать функцию, куда как параметр передать isOriented? Если да, то вот - та ошибка, которая выше.

Comment: В вашем примере в set_edge не передается isOriented в качестве параметра

Comment: Не могли бы вы написать, как это должно выглядеть в итоге?..

Comment: [nested classes](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nested_types)

Comment: @AndreySv, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что  `int isOriented` является членом другого класса. Хотя и `Graph`  является вложенной структурой, но она не может использовать член, принадлежащий обьекту другого типа. Вам нужно хранить в  `Graph` указатель(ссыльку)  на обьект  `DijkstraAlgorythm`, и через него использовать его член `isOriented` или сделать(что логичнее)  `isOriented`
статическим.  И как замечание:  будет понятнее и уместнее, если он будет булевским обьектом, а не целочисленного типа, и не вижу смысла вложенной структуры, доступной всем. Теряется смысль вложенности